# Running specific css for specific part of a page without overriding css of other part of page in laravel?

Tags: php, css, laravel, laravel-blade

Let's elaborate my problem. Think we have 3 template files 
1.Master
2.Child(home)
3.navbar layout(included in home)

Mater->home->navbar

i have 2 external css files which have this css

```
p
{
color:red;
}
```

and

```
p
{
color:blue;
}
```

1st css file is linked in master.blade.php and 2nd css file is linked into navbar.blade.php

I want text color of navbar as blue and text color of home(other than navbar) as red.

Now the output is blue(overriding css which is declared in master).

I don't want to modify css(specificity), Is there anything in laravel like scopes for css.

Answer (score 3):

Are you familiar with  [blade into laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade)?

I think you should define a yield section in your master

```
@yield('css')
```

and then call it in your navbar or etc ... like this

```
 @section('css')
     p
     {
      color:red;
     }
    @endsection
```

and in other files

```
 @section('css')
 p
 {
  color:blue;
 }
@endsection
```

Comment: i mentioned clearly that i don't want any css specificity.What you are doing is really simple and it is css specificity.And i don't require this.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you check the current route, then echo the color in style attribute in-line in your blade file:

```
@if(request()->is('/'))
    <!-- Homepage -->
    <p style="color:red">Hello</p>
@else
    <!-- All Other Pages -->
    <p style="color:blue">Hello</p>
@endif
```

or

```
<p style="color:{{ request()->is('/') ? 'red' : 'blue' }}">Hello</p>
```

Comment: sorry i can't do this as my url is same.As i am rendering into home layout only.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just assign an ID to the different paragraph blocks and target them that way? Or even better, create a utility class for each colour.

```
.text-red {
   color: red;
}
```

And then...

```
<p class="text-red">Lorem ipsum[...]</p>
```

Comment: It really sounds like you're overcomplicating things - generally speaking, loading components as iframes is not a great idea and I'm not sure why you'd want to do so anyway.

Comment: actually i don't want specificity which u have mentioned like class,id, element.I want something like scopes in laravel which we have in AngularJS.But i don't think what i require is possible in laravel blade.

Comment: I just don't really see the point. It seems much easier to make use of utility classes or selectors to ensure that your elements are being styled correctly.